# How to send long list of parameters in URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, url-routing, url-parameters

I have the below link in one of the components of my project

```
<Link to={`http://localhost:8080/project/path/items?ids=18,19`}>
  {itemCount}
</Link>
```

It redirects to another component. That component picks up the `ids` list from url and displays the result

Now my problem is when the `ids` list gets large enough (tens of thousands) it doesn't work.

I need a better approach of handling this
Is it possible through a post request?

Comment: If you are using redux, then save those ids into state and then fetch that state on different component.

Comment: how would it work on opening the link in a new tab?

Comment: A more common design would be to show items on `/items` according to pagination, sorting, filtering and show item on `/item/{id}` which avoids the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `Link` from `react-router`?

The `to` props in `Link` isn't limited to string values. You can pass a state as well like this:

```
  <Link
    key={i.id}
    to={{
      pathname: `/someUrl`,
      state: { someValue: 'asdad', someArray: [1, 2, 3] }
    }}
  >
```

Then at the destination route, you can access the state from `this.props.location.state`. This value only exist for that particular browser history push. If you type the url directly to the browser, `this.props.location.state.someValue` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to handle if you save your id's in local state for the component that's supposed to link to the other component.

```
this.state = {
  ids = [];
}
```

I'm not sure how you get your id's, normally you get them from props or an API. But just to make an example on how to add ids to your state:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    ids: [18, 19, 20, 21]
  })
}
```

This way you'll have  them all in one place, and you can send them to the other component through props.

```
<MyComponent ids={this.state.ids.toString().split(',').join()} />
```

To create your new component (don't know how experienced you are):

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {

    let itemCount = {this.props.ids.length}

    return(
      <Link to={`http://localhost:8080/project/path/items?ids={this.props.ids}`}>
        {itemCount}
      </Link>
    )
  }
}
```

It's important though to know that every element that's supposed to be shown on screen, needs to be kept in the client devices memory. 
Therefor it'll be challenging rendering thousands of element without noticing performance issues. You should prepare yourself for showing a batch of all the id's if you're noticing that the app is getting slow or takes a long time to load.

Two common ways of "batching" a long list is either pagination or lazy-loading.